# Where is the GRLESS key?

Tags: shortcut

I'm watching different tutorials and making with them different models. And in one of those videos an author used keys <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>GRLESS</kbd>.

I've never found such key name before, so I'm wondering now, what is it and where is it?

Comment: Never heard, but see this...https://meshlogic.github.io/posts/blender/addons/toggle-object-wire/ it seems to be the backslash...?

Comment: No, backslash is showing up like a 'BACK_SLASH'... I've just turned on screencast keys, and searching with it. I founded GRLESS in KeyMapItems list, but cannot find what key it assotiated with...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GRLESS stands for "Greater than/Less" and refers to the comparison symbols `<` and `>` which mean "smaller than" or "less then", and "greater than".

In most a standard QWERTY keyboards for English speaking countries (like United States, Canada our Great Britain) these symbols are typically in the period <kbd>.</kbd> and comma <kbd>,</kbd> keys, to the right of the <kbd>M</kbd> key.

Elsewhere however, in other [international QWERTY layouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Specific_language_variants) it is common to find a dedicated key with both greater than <kbd>></kbd> and less then <kbd><</kbd> keys bundled together, toggled by <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier key.

For Portuguese, Spanish, Greek, Italian, Danish, among  and others layout for example they are located towards the bottom left corner of the keyboard, next to the <kbd>Z</kbd> key.